# JavaScript reference in Sharepoint 13

Tags: javascript, element, sharepoint-2013

I have just started to learn Sharepoint2013, starting with developing a feature, which includes an element called testElement for instance, which should show a button as a ribbon and runs a script to enable or disable this ribbon.
the XMLof the element looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="RibAct" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="RibButton"
                  Command="Command"
                  Sequence="15" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="CommHandler"
          CommandAction="javascript:javascriptFunction();"
          EnabledScript="javascript:enable();"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.Scripts"
                Location="ScriptLink"
                ScriptSrc="/_layouts/ApplicationPageFolder/Custom.js" />
</Elements>
```

my enable function is located in Custom.js, after deploying the Feature, I can activate and deactivate it in my Site, I can see the Ribbon in the right place, but still it is not enabled, getting an error that the enable function has not been found.

Can someone tell me please what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem and found this [solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85806/using-javascript-file-in-elements-xml) to the original question:

1. SharePoint 2013 requires the hive (15) directory specified, i.e. ScriptSrc="/_layouts/**15**/ApplicationPageFolder/Custom.js".
2. Additionally, values of Command in Button and CommandUIHandler [should match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff458385(v=office.15).aspx).

Fixed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="RibAct" Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
    <CommandUIExtension>
      <CommandUIDefinitions>
        <CommandUIDefinition Location="Ribbon.Documents.Copies.Controls._children">
          <Button Id="RibButton"
                  Command="TheSameValue"
                  Sequence="15" />
        </CommandUIDefinition>
      </CommandUIDefinitions>
      <CommandUIHandlers>
        <CommandUIHandler
          Command="TheSameValue"
          CommandAction="javascript:javascriptFunction();"
          EnabledScript="javascript:enable();"/>
      </CommandUIHandlers>
    </CommandUIExtension>
  </CustomAction>
  <CustomAction Id="Ribbon.Library.Actions.Scripts"
                Location="ScriptLink"
                ScriptSrc="/_layouts/15/ApplicationPageFolder/Custom.js" />
</Elements>
```